# How to fix ESLint errors 'no-loop-func' and 'no-await-in-loop' in while loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop, eslint

This code gets child TreeNodes from depth by parent, until you get the first level node. How to fix ESLint errors with 'no-loop-func' and 'no-await-in-loop', without supressions and changing rules. Didn't find any examples for while loop.

```
    const nodes = await loadNodeList();
    let buffNodes = [];
    let buff = {};    
    
    buff = await loadNodeById(id);
    
    while (!nodes.find((elm) => elm.id === buff.id)) { // Function declared in a loop contains unsafe references to variable(s) 'buff'.(no-loop-func)
      buff = await loadNodeById(buff.parent.id); // Unexpected `await` inside a loop.(no-await-in-loop)
      buffNodes.push(buff);
    }
```

Comment: Have you [read the documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-await-in-loop)? (Make sure not to skip the "When Not To Use It" part).

Comment: @Quentin do you think this is the same case?

Comment: Are you asking me if the `no-await-in-loop` documentation for ESLint is the correct documentation for the `no-await-in-loop` linting message you are getting?

Comment: Actually, I would like to know if this code is normal or not, it works well, but since I installed ESLint I started asking myself question "Am I doing something wrong?"

Comment: Linters are highly *opinionated*. Read their documentation to determine the reasoning behind the rules. Then decide if you (a) agree in general and (b) if you do, if this particular code is an exception or not.

Comment: You may want to switch to recursion here. Btw there's no problem with the things the linter points out, but I suspect that it's a bug that the first `buff` is not put in the `buffNodes` list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-await-in-loop

Fast answer

```
/* eslint-disable no-await-in-loop */
for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1) {
  const res = await DoSomething();
}
/* eslint-enable no-await-in-loop */
```

Also, you can try to use for await of ...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of

Comment: That doesn't "fix" it, it turns the check off.

Comment: Yes, but im trying to find way without suppressions

Comment: @JohnTaylor edit your eslint rules config and disable it then.

Comment: @ElvisAdomnica and without disabling rules ;)

Comment: @JohnTaylor, You can use "warn" instead of "off".
Using this you do not disable the rules, but simply reduce its significance.

Comment: "*Also, you can try to use for await of ...*" the code isn't consuming an async iterable, so I don't see the point of using this. Unless you suggest something like changing the code to be an async generator which can probably work but seems like a rather huge change just to avoid a linter error.